# How to replace the current svn version of a branch with an older one?

Tags: svn

I would like to replace my entire branch with an older version of itself. How do I do this?

I'm fully aware of the reverse merge command, but that command will completely ignore any file that wasn't part of the commit that lead to the revision number i'm after.

For example:

Let's say we have a project project like this:

Project "My project" - branch 2.x

- Hello.java
- World.java

Now if we proceed like this:

- The branch starts at revision 100 (as a reminder, the initial commit of branch **does not contains any file** in the changelog).
- We add a new file, World.java, and reach revision 101.
- We modify file Hello.java and reach revision 102.
- We realize that revisions 101 and 102 are flawed, so we want to go back to revision 100.

How do i rollback the branch 2.0 of project "My project" to revision 100?

If i try to perform a reverse merge, nothing will happen, because the initial commit of the branch doesn't contain any changed file.

Is there maybe something i don't understand about reverse merging? It seems to me rolling there is no way to rollback an entire project to a specific version, whether some files were changed in that version or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roll back the **range** of "flawed" revisions.

```
svn merge -r 102:100 .
svn commit -m "Rollback the branch 2.0 to revision 100"
```

Read about it the Subversion Red Book [Undoing Changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.branchmerge.commonuses.html#svn.branchmerge.commonuses.undo) section.

Comment: Indeed, i got confused a bit when reading the documentation, but this is the proper way to do it! Thanks, and sorry for the late reply!